# How to check if a string contains characters or numbers C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, string

I have probable variable value as follows "Name_1" and "1535".

I want a library function either in C++ or C# to determine if the variable value is "1535" (it is numeric) or if it is "Name_1" (it is a name).

Let me know what available functions there are?

Comment: Do you have any ranges on the numbers? Is "-2" a value that could occur? Is "3.1415"? Is "3E-4"?

Comment: @Rahul, If you find someone's answer as correct, mark it as Answer. Seeing your accept-rate as 0% would make others reluctant to answer on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is ok to regard any non-integer string as "character":

[Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx):

```
String variable = "1234";
Integer dummyresult
if Int32.TryParse(variable,dummyresult)
{
    // variable is numeric
}
else
{
    // variable is not numeric
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "1235";

Console.WriteLine("String is numeric: " + Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[0-9]+$"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) comes in handy for this:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

bool IsNumber(const char *s) {
  using boost::lexical_cast;

  try {
    boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
    return true;
  } catch (std::bad_cast&) {
    return false;
  }
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  std::cout << av[1] << ": " << std::boolalpha << IsNumber(av[1]) << "\n";
}
```

---

**EDIT**: If Boost isn't available to you, try this:

```
bool IsNumber2(const char *s) {

  std::istringstream stream(s);
  stream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

  int i;
  if( (stream >> i) && stream.eof() )
    return true;
  return false;
}
```